# Is there a way to check what oracle stored procdure is loading while running

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I have a stored procedure which has been running for a long time and I don't find any entry for that in v$session_longops. Is there a way to check on the current status of that?

Also, am pretty new to oracle. So is there a way to check on the amount of data the proc is trying to load into a table just like work flow monitor in informatica?

I am a dev and am using Oracle 12c.

Comment: if you want to keep track of your proc via v$session_longops - you have to build that INTO your procedure code, ORACLE_BASE examples here https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/dbms_application_info#set_session_longops

Answer (score 0):

Check with a view called gv$session.  Column sql_text should let you identify your session and column rows_processed should tell you how many rows, if any, have been processed.

You may need to ask your DBA to grant you access to that view.